# Transform *.dll to *.cs

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine

I have a dll file that I want to decompile. I know there are ILSpy, dotPeek and similar programs, but I have yet to find one that will actually create the cs file.

The dll I'm dealing with has several hundred classes in it and it would take days to manually copy everything.

Is there a tool that will take a dll file and return a set of cs files?

Comment: Yes it is. I'll delete it. It was worded differently enough I couldn't find it though.

Comment: Actually, admins will because I do not want to be banned from asking. I apologize for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ILSpy**

If you have loaded a dll in ILSpy, select File -> Save Code... or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

- If you select the dll in the tree, then it will create a cs
  project in a selected folder, along with C# files for each
  class.
- If you select just a class in the tree, it will create just
  the C# file for the class.

See [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

Comment: It seems that my room temperature is higher than my IQ. And I'm very cold.